# Why I need a password to get access to the jupyter notebook when I use docker machine?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

When I use docker machine to open my Jupyter notebook, there is a strange issue happening. The website needs me to enter password so that I can get access to the notebook. It is really strange! Do you know why? Actually, I am using my docker machine to use tensorflow to learn machine learning. I use docker container and terminal to get tensorflow and try to open jupyter notebook on the browser. But it lets me to enter password to use notebook after the Jupyter appeared on my browser.

Comment: Why it is downvoted? I feel this question kind of confuses me, I am still trying to fix the problem! Since my reputation only has 5 points so I couldn't upload my picture(I don't know why stackoverflow gives users such a unequal restrictions!),  so maybe I didn't illustrate more details about the issue!  However, I am thinking probably I need to reset my jupyter password to see how it works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can supply the password to Tensor Flows docker container through an environment variable called PASSWORD like this:
`docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -e "PASSWORD=abc123" gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow`

Just add the -e parameter and specify you evironment variable after that.

If you look through the github repository for the docker image you can find this snippet at the bottom of [jupyter_notebook_config.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/docker/jupyter_notebook_config.py)

```
# sets a password if PASSWORD is set in the environment
if 'PASSWORD' in os.environ:
  c.NotebookApp.password = passwd(os.environ['PASSWORD'])
  del os.environ['PASSWORD']
```

Comment: +1 It's so annoying that this and other little nuances along the way are not mentioned on Google's "Getting Started" page. Doesn't really help people get started.